# Error while installing jekyll on Debian 12

Tags: jekyll

I want to install jekyll in Debian 12. I have already ruby and gem latest versions. I typed the command **gem install jekyll bundle** that I took from the official website . But I am having the error:

> you don't have permissions for the /var/lib/gems/3.1.0.

I tried to use the code **gem install jekyll bundle** from the official website but still the problem persists.

Comment: The [generic Linux instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/other-linux/) include the [Ubuntu steps](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ubuntu/), which include modifying your shell startup files such that Gems are installed in you home directory; did you follow those steps?